# Can I use IFTTT in Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

I was looking at the applets and it showed quite a few for the Google Assistant. But those are for normal when you are in the assistant. Can I use IFTTT when I make an Action on Google?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want or need IFTTT for your own Actions. Applets for the Assistant are mostly to enable very simple voice commands that front other APIs. Can you elaborate on how you would want this to work from a user POV?

Comment: @Prisoner I was thinking that it would open a huge amount of possibilities. Like accessing contacts is not possible directly from actions on google, but with ifttt that can be implemented. Similarly for other services. Are you able to understand my POV?

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to use the [IFTTT webhook](https://ifttt.com/maker_webhooks).

[image]

Then, in your fulfillment code that your Action on Google calls (likely using API.AI), you could call the IFTTT webhook. In this way, what you say to Action on Google can be used to trigger an IFTTT applet.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Google has an entry at IFTTT: https://ifttt.com/google_assistant

However... from the description of the Triggers, it looks like this is a bogus listing that actually has nothing to do with IFTTT. They each say:

> This trigger fires when you say “Ok Google” to the Google Assistant followed by a phrase you choose.

That would happen anyways and has nothing to do with IFTTT!